# How do I convert an mcrypt_ecb() function to mcrypt_generic()?

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt, php-7

In PHP 5.5 [mcrypt_ecb()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-ecb.php) is depreciated. I need to convert my Cryptogrpahy class into [mcrypt_generic()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic.php) and [mdecrypt_generic()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mdecrypt-generic.php), but the docs are have sparse details on how to use TripleDES.
Any help in converting the encrypt() and decrypt() functions would be appreciated so I can prepare for the move to PHP 7.

```
class Crypt {
private $_key  = __CLASS__;
function __construct($key = null) {
    is_null($key)  || ($this->Key  = $key);
}

function __set($property, $value) {
    switch ($property) {
        case 'Key' : return $this->_setKey($value);
    }
}

function __get($property) {
    switch ($property) {
        case 'Key' : return $this->_key;
    }
}

public function encrypt($data) {
    $k = $this->_key;
    if (strlen($k) > 24)
        $k = substr($k, 0, 24);
    return base64_encode(base64_encode(mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_TripleDES, $k, $data, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT)));
}

public function decrypt($crypt) {
    $k = $this->_key;
    if (strlen($k) > 24)
        $k = substr($k, 0, 24);
    return trim(mcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_TripleDES, $k, base64_decode(base64_decode($crypt)), MCRYPT_DECRYPT));
}

protected function _setKey($key) {
    $this->_key = (string) $key;
}
}
```

Comment: [Updated docs](http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=338134) to reference mcrypt_encrypt and mcrypt_decrypt instead of the generic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_TripleDES, $k, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_modename)`
`mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_TripleDES, $k, base64_decode(base64_decode($crypt)), MCRYPT_MODE_modename)`

http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.constants.php

Comment: Thanks, this is lmost what I need, but I'm getting a bunch of warnings because of MCRYPT_MODE_modename. If I change that to MCRYPT_MODE_CBC then it requires an initialisation vector, which isn't present in the original code. Any clue?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to write that... In the link I provided you have all mcrypt modes. You are supposed to change MCRYPT_MODE_modename to some mode you find most useful for you

Comment: That's my problem.. I have no idea what to change MCRYPT_MODE_modename to, based on my current code!

Comment: You were using ECB and you could just to continue to use it. So, your mode would be "MCRYPT_MODE_ECB".